# Traversing multiple folders for searching the same file in multiple foders in python

Tags: python-2.7

search the same file in multiple folders

I have tried with os.walk(path) but I am not getting the nested folders traversing

```
        for current_root, folders, file_names in os.walk(self.path, topdown=True):
            for i in folders:
                print i
                for filename in file_names:
                    count+= 1
                    file_path = os.path.join(current_root + '\\' + filename)
                    #print file_path
                    self.location_dictionary[file_path] = filename
```

in my code, it will print all folders but it will not enter to the nested folders recursively 
ex: I have subdir,subdir1,subdir2 and in subdir I have another dir called abc
in subdir and abc both contain same file name I want to read that file

Comment: `os.path.join(current_root + '\\' + filename)` ??? => `os.path.join(current_root,filename)`

Comment: don't nest directory & files loops.

Answer (score 0):

`os.walk` does not work that way.

for each `current_root` it traverses, it provides the list of directories and files directly under it.

You're nesting the loops, which does ... well I don't know...

Here you don't need the folder (so just mute the argument). `current_root` already contains that info for your files:

```
for current_root, _, file_names in os.walk(self.path, topdown=True):
    for filename in file_names:
        count+= 1
        file_path = os.path.join(current_root,filename)
        #print file_path
        self.location_dictionary[file_path] = filename
```

aside: creating a dictionary with full file as key and filename as value looks, well, not what you want (the same information could be stored in a `set` or `list` and `os.path.basename` could be used to compute the filename. Maybe it's reverse (filename => full path), provided that there are no duplicate filenames.